Eigenstates of position in the Heisenberg picture
In the Heisenberg picture, the position operator becomes time dependent. This also means that the eigenstates of position are time dependent. In the Schrödinger picture it was possible for my state $| \psi \rangle$ to be, at time $t=0$, in an eigenstate of position. The state then evolved according to the Schrödinger equation. Now, I am not clear how I would describe the same situation in the Heisenberg picture. Since the eigenstates of position evolve in time, it seems as though my state vector $| \psi \rangle$ must also evolve in time, which contradicts the Heisenberg picture. I think somehow what happens is that $| \psi \rangle = | x,t=0 \rangle$ and then the eigenstates of position change, but $| \psi \rangle$ does not (as it is fixed in the Heisenberg picture). Is this reasonable?

Your last sentence is correct. The eigenstates of position change in time, but $|\psi\rangle$ does not.  And the eigenstates change according to a time evolution operator that is the time-reverse of the time evolution operator in the Schrodinger picture.

Consider that $|\Psi_{x,0}\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the position operator $\hat x(0)$ at time $0$  with eigenvalue $x$. I.e.,
$$ \hat x(0) |\Psi_{x,0}\rangle = x |\Psi_{x,0}\rangle$$.
Let $U_t: \mathscr H \to \mathscr H$ be the time evolution operator. In the Heisenberg picture, we have $\hat x(t) = U_t^\dagger \hat x(0) U_t$. Thus, we have that
\begin{align}
\hat x(t) U_t^\dagger |\Psi_{x,0}\rangle
&= U_t^\dagger \hat x(0) U_t U_t^\dagger |\Psi_{x,0}\rangle \\
&= U_t^\dagger \hat x(0)|\Psi_{x,0}\rangle \\
&= x U_t^\dagger |\Psi_{x,0}\rangle\,.
\end{align}
So $|\Psi_{x,t}\rangle := U_t^\dagger |\Psi_{x,0}\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat x(t)$ with eigenvalue $x$.
Remark: Be aware, that all of this discussion is non-rigorous, since $\hat x(0)$ is unbounded and has a continuous spectrum. So in a mathematical sense, there are now Eigenvectors of $\hat x(0)$ that would lie in the Hilbert space $\mathscr H$.
